Swiper with thumbnails. Click on the last visible slide of thumbnail doesn't slide to new view of slides. Slick slider and Splide does that
UPD: I've used rewind instead of loop, and it's seem to be alright.
I've almost made it work, but after testing the click on "play" button which shoul take me to last slide and moving around it simply starts to work very strangely and I'm too tired to try something.
https://swiperjs.com/demos#thumbs-gallery-loop - here you can see the demo and if you click last visible slide on thumbnail it's only slides to that slide on main slider, but doesn't change the appearance of thumbnail. I want it to slide and show other, next slides.
Here's video with example of swiper and other slider which does what I need:
https://imgur.com/a/blJIzpf
I've tried to do it like this:
<script>
const galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.product__thumbnails', {
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 14,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.slider-nav__next',
  },
});

const galleryTop = new Swiper('.product__gallery', {
  loop: true,
  autoHeight: true,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  thumbs: {
    swiper: galleryThumbs,
  },
});

galleryThumbs.on('click', function () {
    const lastVisibleSlide = galleryThumbs.visibleSlides[galleryThumbs.visibleSlides.length - 1];
    const lastVisibleIndex = parseInt(lastVisibleSlide.getAttribute('data-swiper-slide-index'));
    const nextIndex = lastVisibleIndex + galleryThumbs.params.slidesPerView;
    const currentIndex = parseInt(galleryThumbs.clickedSlide?.getAttribute("data-swiper-slide-index"));
    console.log(currentIndex, galleryThumbs.slides.length);
    console.log(lastVisibleIndex, "- lastVisibleIndex");
    if (currentIndex + 1 >= galleryThumbs.slides.length) {
      galleryThumbs.slideTo(0);
    } else if (currentIndex === lastVisibleIndex) {
      galleryThumbs.slideToLoop(currentIndex - 1);
    }
});

{% if has_video %}
  $('button.product__play').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    galleryTop.slideTo({{ video_sequence_number }} - 1);
    const slideVideo = $('.slider__gallery').find('.slider__slide[data-slide="video"]');
    if (slideVideo.length > 0) {
      slideVideo.find(".deferred-media__poster").trigger('click');
    } else {
      console.error('Video element not found.');
    }
  });
  {% endif %}
</script>

When I click on slide, it check if it's the last of visible ones and moves to next slides. It work ok, but when it's reaches the last slide, it's starts to work strangely. I've discovered "slideToLoop" and it seemed to help, but I've encountered some other problems. But I don't think that matters.
I think it works okay without the loop, but I need the loop.
The problem is, I just can't find the code which solves that problem. But I hope maybe someone has some resources here.
You can see what I've tried in my code, I guess. I've tried to use slick and Splide, but there was other problems with them for solving which I simply don't have enough motivation anymore.
UPD: I've slightly changed the code, and it's works somehow alright, but there is a new problem:
https://imgur.com/a/9jPw0ce
When I click "play video" it takes me to the end, when I slide to first other slide and press button again, it shows the video like it's a first slide
